# SSRS Reports Deployment with Dafault Date

Tags: reporting-services

I have developed a report with Date values set to default to Current date (= NOW ()) using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I then deployed the report to the web portal successfully. When I run the report using the Visual studio I am getting the right report data. When I run the deployed report from the portal the report data is completely different and does not match with the report that I generated using the Visual studio. I tried deleting and redeploying the report and still I am getting the same result. Could some one suggest a resolution for this or work around.

Hem

Answer (score 0):

If your report uses a shared datasource then the most likely problem is that the datasource on the server is not the same as the datasource that VS is using on your local PC.

By default datasources are NOT overwritten when you deploy a report.

Got the web portal and then to the datasource folder. Look in there for datasource with the same name as the one your report uses. Check the credentials, server, database etc. Once you confirm that this is different from the one in Visual Studio, you can do one of the following...

1. If you are CERTAIN that no other reports rely on this datasource then you can either edit it via the web portal or simply delete it via the web portal  and redeploy it from VS
2. As above regarding other reports using the same daatsource... Temporarily change the report project setting to allow overwriting of datasoucres and redeploy
3. You can rename your datasource in VS to something unique, then when you deploy the report again, a new datasource will be created on the server with the new name and your report will point to that new version

Comment: Thank you very much. The reporting server is not connected to the SQL database. I am asking my IT team to look into this.